# Modify the default list view to expand the "Description" field insdie the view table

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list-view, page-layout, display-template

I have use the default view for my SharePoint 2013 issue tracking list , as follow:-

[image]

But is there a way to make the “Description" field size larger ? I know this field will expand automatically , but the idea is that I want it to have a fixed size and to expand horizontally at least double the current area ?

Answer (score 3):

Since a view for Issue Tracking list is rendered as a table you could use the CSS to define column width, for example:

```
tr.ms-viewheadertr th:nth-child(5) {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

> Note: The column is selected by its index using [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

**Result**

[image]

Probably the easiest way to apply the changes would be to insert the specified CSS (do not forget enclose it using `style` tag) on the page using `Content Editor` or `Script Editor` web parts.

Comment: thanks for the help it worked well, but can i ask you if modifying the view in this way can be overridden by any future update to SharePoint ? or this can not be overridden by any update, and it is a safe way to modify the list view layout?

Comment: If by future update you mean Cummulative  Updates and Service Packs then yes, it will not affect the customized view

Comment: I have another minor comment, after i added the <style> i have noted that the "Item " & "List" tabs will be hidden, till the user select at-least one item.. if i remove the Script Editor which contains the <style>, then the "item" & "List" tabs are going to be displayed again when the use visit the page... can you advice on this please?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the list view webpart in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Then click on `Customize XSLT`

Search in the code for

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_header.Description" ddwrt:dvt_mode="header" match="FieldRef[@Name='Description']" mode="header" ddwrt:ghost="hide">
<th nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
<xsl:attribute name="class">
```

Now, I change the code:

```
<th nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
```

To

```
<th scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" style ="width: 350px; white-space:normal;min-width:350px">
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b8e2f14-81ab-4d57-808b-d452001e0ccf/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013

Comment: can you advice please from where i can access this code ?